# Setting express from pug to ejs

Tags: express, pug, sublimetext3, ejs

I am learning node a bit and by using sublime I installed express by cmd, now I got inside `views` directory `.pug files`, is here a way while I am installing express to set them as `.ejs`?

Like its on webstorm to ask me which one would I like to use, or is it package for sublime that is setting express as on webstorm maybe?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is change `app.set('view engine', 'pug')` to `app.set('view engine', 'ejs')`, in your Express application, but I think you should give pug a go! It's very straightforward and you can read the documentation here: https://pugjs.org/

Comment: I did it by installing npm install --save express ejs, I like ejs more than pug/jade